# What is the complexity of recurrence $T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/n$

Tags: time-complexity

What is the complexity of the follwoing recurrence? $$T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/n$$

I highly suspect the answer to be $O(1)$, because your work reduces by $1$ each time, so by the $n$th time it would be $T(n-n) = T(0)$ and your initial task reduces to 0.

Comment: @DavidRicherby has right. Actually, this question is the example for non-decreasing $f(n)$ in $T(n) = T(n-1) + f(n)$  http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/24082/1152

Comment: *Problems* have complexity, *algorithms* have running times, (mathematical) *functions* have growth rates. Are you asking about the growth rate of the mathematical function $T(n)$ or the difficulty of computing it?

Comment: I have no idea how these things are being taught today. However I am
rather surprised by this apparent **misuse or abuse of the word
"complexity"**, and by the fact that no one is reacting to it.  From
what I understand, this can only reinforce the complete conceptual
mishmash that seems to encumber the brains of too many students.
As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with complexity, and **the
study of asymptotic limits and of Landau notation (Big O and its
brothers and sisters) is not the study of complexity, but only a tool
for it, and for other purposes.** (simultaneous @DavidRiche

Comment: @babou Yes, this is indeed widespread. Even research papers talk about "complexity of this algorithm".

Comment: @babou Everyone thinks "Oh, it's $O(\text{something})$, it must have something to do with time complexity."

Comment: @Raphael You are right. However it bothers me a bit less as the concepts are very close, complexity being about the cost of algorithms that solve the problem. But asymptotic analysis is just a piece of math that has lots of other uses. Still, being precise and using the right words is essential when doing science.

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By unfolding $$T(n) = T(n-1) + \frac{1}{n} = T(n-2) + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} = \dots=T(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$$
Now we can easily approximate the sum on the RHS using that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \le 1 + \int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x} dx = 1+ \log{n} - \log{1} = 1+ \log{n}$$
Therefore $T(n) \equiv O(\log{n})$

Comment: The answer would be better if it criticized the misuse of the word complexity.

Comment: The inequality is now wrong. In fact, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \log n + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, where $\gamma \approx 0.577 > 0$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Thanks again @Yuval Filmus. The inequality is correct now. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

This answer assumed that the OP was looking for the time-complexity of an algorithm that would evaluate the recurrence, so it's probably wrong.

---

Whatever you do, you *have* to iterate $n$ times, whatever the base case/starting value. So as $n$ grows without bound, the number of operations also grows linearly with $n$ - implying that the recurrence is $O(n)$.

Look at it this way: To calculate $T(n)$, you need $T(n-1)$, which in turn depends on $T(n-2)$, and so on all way till $T(0)$ (or whatever the lowest allowed value of $n$ is).

Each time, you calculate $\frac{1}{k}$ and add it to the next lower value of $T(k)$, doing $O(1)$ work each time, $n$ times - which adds up to $O(n)$ complexity.

---

In fact, you can easily represent $T(n)$ in general as

$$
T(n) = T(0) + \sum^n_{k=1}{\frac{1}{k}}
$$

(which, if you're curious, is equal to $T(0) +H_n$, where $H_n$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).)

Comment: Taking into account the asymptotics of the harmonic numbers, the final answer is $T(n) = \log n + O(1)$.

Comment: When writing my answer I assumed that OP was looking for the complexity of an algorithm that would calculate the answer, so . . . you're correct.

Comment: I guess you computed the cost of a given algorithm, rather than the complexity of the problem it solves. But it is as good an interpretation of the misuse of the word complexity as any other.